# ¿Cuál es el término más largo registrado en el DLE que no contiene vocales?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, dle

¿Existen términos en español registrados en el DLE (de más de dos letras, y excluyendo siglas o afijos) que no contengan vocales? ¿Cuál es el más largo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí que hay, de momento el más largo que hemos encontrado es el siguiente:

> **[pchs](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SEsGpyh)**
>
> 1. interj. **pche**.

Y siguiendo el enlace obtenemos su definición:

> **[pche](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SErsYzc)**
>
> 1. interj. U. para denotar indiferencia, displicencia o reserva.

Ejemplo de uso:

> *La impresión que motiva, ciertamente no escasea del ridículo en los primeros momentos; la talla de los caballos, el chic de los trenes que arrastran, lo abigarrado y especial de las libreas que los aurigas lucen, los deliciosos grupos ó solos, orígenes de boato tanto, todo ocasiona un asombro extraño, peculiar, sui géneris, que oscila entre sonrisa de compasión é imperceptible gesto de indiferencia; ese mover de hombros que acaba en los labios con un ¡pchs! característico.*
>
> Ximeno Ximénez (Alberto Díaz de la Quintana), "Siluetas filipinas", 1887 (Filipinas).

Más ejemplos [aquí](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=Pchs&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) pulsando el botón "Recuperar".

Parece poco probable encontrar una palabra más larga con las mencionadas características, dado que las palabras en español que contienen más consonantes seguidas tienen cinco de ellas, como **[ángstrom](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2fLHwBK)** o **[nietzscheano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QUrXG8W)**.